# convert Zend Db Select query to sql query

Tags: sql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

Are there any ways to convert Zend db Select or Zend DB query to SQL query before querying the database? Any other workarounds?

As I want to build a more complex SQL query that Zend DB cannot handle, without modifying my current Zend db code structure.

Comment: You are going to handcode an SQL query ? I am not sure how you can do that without changing or removing the Zend_Db_Select specific code

Answer (score 6):

You can convert a Zend db Select object to string by `$select->__toString()`

Answer (score 3):

You can always `echo $select` which will return string with plain SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

For a `Zend\Db\Sql\Select` object (In Zend 2.2),

`$select->getSqlString();` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Zend Framework `1.*` you can use assemble

```php
echo $select->assemble();
```